# Keyboard Shortcut to switch from search result to found file

Tags: linux-mint, nemo

I am using Nemo on an Mint Cinnamon Distribution.

I use Nemo to search for files with the shortcut `ctrl`+`f`. Typing the file name gives me the search result.

But how do I switch the focus to the result panel, so I can cycle through the results and select the appropriate? Even when there is only one result `ctrl`+`o` doesn't open the file. `F6` also doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pulled up Mint Cinnamon on DistroTest.net, poked around at Nemo, and found a way. It's not obvious, but it seems to work.

Nemo has three views, each with a keyboard shortcut: Icon View (Ctrl+1), List View (Ctrl+2), and Compact View (Ctrl+3). After performing a search and seeing the results, changing the view places focus in the results panel. For example, if your default view is List View and you perform a search, typing `Ctrl+3` after your search changes the current view to Compact View while also placing keyboard focus in the results pane. You should then be able to use the `arrow keys` to move focus to a particular file, the `Enter key` to open or execute a file, etc.

Comment: Thanks, while weird that works!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an ideal solution, but... After doing your search and seeing the results displayed, try hitting the `down arrow` key four times. It moves the focus to the results panel in Caja, and Caja, like Nemo, is a Nautilus derivitive, so it may work in Nemo as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately, that doesn't work for me.